# Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(frame:)' for class when instantiating a subclass of UISegementedControl

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm getting the following error when I try to use an instance of `MySegmentControl` in the code below. The error occurs right after the app is being launched.

Any idea what am I missing?

> Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(frame:)' for class 'TestingSubclassing.MySegmentControl'

#### Subclass of UISegementedControl

import UIKit

```
class MySegmentControl: UISegmentedControl {

    init(actionName: Selector) {
        let discountItems = ["One" , "Two"]
        super.init(items: discountItems)

        self.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        self.addTarget(self, action: actionName, for: .valueChanged)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

#### ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let segmentOne: MySegmentControl = {
        let segment1 = MySegmentControl(actionName:  #selector(segmentAction))
        return segment1
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(segmentOne)
    }

    @objc func segmentAction (sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        print("segmentAction")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call `super.init(frame` and insert the segments *manually*.

And you have to add a `target` parameter to the custom `init(actionName` method.

```
class MySegmentControl: UISegmentedControl {

    init(actionName: Selector, target: Any?) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        insertSegment(withTitle: "Two", at: 0, animated: false)
        insertSegment(withTitle: "One", at: 0, animated: false)
        self.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        self.addTarget(target, action: actionName, for: .valueChanged)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you really meant to insert both segments at 0 index or should one be inserted at 1?

Comment: Yes I do. When `One` is inserted `Two` moves to index 1

Comment: @ vadian - Based on my original code, do have any idea why am I getting error... **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TestingSubclassing.MySegmentControl segmentActionWithSender:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8ec3507ef0'**? I have tried `let segment1 = MySegmentControl(actionName: #selector(segmentAction(sender:)))`  and `let segment1 = MySegmentControl(actionName: "segmentAction")` but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Assigning `self` to the target inside the subclass makes no sense. You have to add a `target` parameter. I updated the answer.