# Error: Unrecognised selector sent to instance when tap on UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm getting an error when tap on one of the segments to trigger the action.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TestingSubclassing.MySegmentControl segmentActionWithSender:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9217907750'

```
import UIKit

class MySegmentControl: UISegmentedControl {

    var actionName:Selector
    init(actionName: Selector) {
        self.actionName = actionName

        super.init(frame: .zero)

        insertSegment(withTitle: "Two", at: 0, animated: false)
        insertSegment(withTitle: "One", at: 1, animated: false)

        self.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        self.addTarget(self, action: self.actionName, for: .valueChanged)

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

#### Usage in ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let segmentOne: MySegmentControl = {
        let segment1 = MySegmentControl(actionName:  #selector(segmentAction))
        return segment1
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(segmentOne)
    }

    @objc func segmentAction(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        print("segmentAction")
    }
}
```

I have also tried changing the selector as follow.

`let segment1 = MySegmentControl(actionName: #selector(segmentAction(sender:)))` 
and 
`let segment1 = MySegmentControl(actionName: "segmentAction")`

Comment: The problem is that you have set the action target to `self`, which means that the selector will be called on the segment controller, not the view controller.  You would probably be better using a delegation pattern or providing a callback closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be a newbie!
You should remove `self.addTarget(self, action: self.actionName, for: .valueChanged)` in `class MySegmentControl`, add added the below the function `viewDidLoad()`:

```swift
segmentOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentAction(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

Comment: I'm ok with this solution, but, FYI - I was originally trying to pass the selector as a parameter to minimize the amount of code in the `ViewController` and possibly create a `UISegmentedControl` with one line of code e.g. `let segment1 = MySegmentControl(actionName:  #selector(segmentAction))`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @fs_tigre See my (edited) answer to your previous question.

Comment: @vadian - That's exactly what I was looking for. Here is the exact answer to my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59556459/use-of-unimplemented-initializer-initframe-for-class-when-instantiating-a-s